# Python csv.DictReader does not split at comma's

Tags: python, python-2.7

A row in my csv file:

> console_ip,spsstatus,spsversion
>
> 172.19.126.182,Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x4 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)^M,Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)

I am getting:

> {'console_ip': '172.19.126.182', 'spsversion': None, 'spsstatus': 'Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x4 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)'}
> {'console_ip': '', 'spsversion': None, 'spsstatus': 'Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)'}

Expected just one element in a dictionary:

> {'console_ip': '172.19.126.182', 'spsversion': 'Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x4 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)','spsstatus': 'Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)'}

My code:

```
f = 'consolespsdata/hostIpmi_bom52'
with open(f, 'rU') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=",")
    for line in csv_reader:
    if line['console_ip'] is not None:
        print line
```

Im wondering what might be causing this issue.

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: Updated the overviw @sam

Comment: My results are different from yours. Please see my post.

Answer (score 1):

## I get something different from what you see.

---

**a.csv**

```
console_ip,spsstatus,spsversion

172.19.126.182,Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x4 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)^M,Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)
```

**b.py**

```
import csv
f = 'a.csv'
with open(f, 'rU') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=",")
    for line in csv_reader:
        if line['console_ip'] is not None:
            print line
```

**python b.py**

```
{'console_ip': '172.19.126.182', 
 'spsversion': 'Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x1 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)', 
 'spsstatus': 'Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x6 netfn=0x6 lun=0x0 cmd=0x4 rsp=0x83): Unknown (0x83)^M'
}
```

---

## A more succinct example.

**a.csv**

```
k1,k2,k3

val1,val2,val3
val4,val5,val6
```

**b.py**

```
import csv
f = 'a.csv'
with open(f, 'rU') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=",")
    for line in csv_reader:
        if line['k1'] is not None:
            print line
```

**python b.py**

```
{'k3': 'val3', 'k2': 'val2', 'k1': 'val1'}
{'k3': 'val6', 'k2': 'val5', 'k1': 'val4'}
```

Which seems to work fine. If the second example works for you, maybe special characters in your `csv` files are causing issues.

Comment: how does this example work for you and not me, :-/ 2nd example does work though

Comment: Yeah what you are getting is indeed quite strange.. Try to process your csv row by row. (Make a copy, which contains only the first 1/2 rows, and experiment.)

Comment: you are correct, it worked with one and say 3 records(I added the neighboring records from my csv) but is failing for my entire csv which has some 108 records. This is so weird.

Comment: Could you verify that each row in your csv has exactly 2 commas (since there are 3 columns)?